# How can I download maps from google maps api from my own application?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on an app which requires that the user can download maps as in google maps but from this app, and then charge this maps for offline navigation.

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

i'm currently using setOnMyLocationChangeListener, I know that it's deprecated and must use FusedLocationProviderApi but I don't know how

```
 mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 18);
            mMap.animateCamera(cu);
        }
    });
```